# docker-compose: only validate YAML, don't follow path or resolve .env files

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, github-actions, gitea

I have a gitea-instance with Actions (like GitHub Actions) and want to validate `docker-compose.yml` files before deploying them onto the server.
I have found in the docs the parameter `--no-path-resolution` and this works fine with the volume-binds (I'm mounting path and not using volumes), but not with `.env` files.

Gitea workflow:

```bash
sudo docker compose config --no-path-resolution > /dev/null
```

Results in:

> Failed to load ./data/app/.env: open ./data/app/.env: no such file or directory

How can I tell docker compose to ignore the `.env` file, and just validate the YAML format?